# Android- attaching InfoWindowAdapter to GoogleMap with multiple ClusterManagers

Tags: android, infowindow

I have a Google Maps V2 and in my setUpMap() method I am attaching the GoogleMap an infoWindowAdapter like so:

```
ClusterManager<OffersMarker> rentClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);
gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(rentClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
```

There is more code but the point is that this works and I can see the infoWindow when I click on the marker.

Since I have two ClusterManagers thou I have a problem:

```
ClusterManager<OffersMarker> rentClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);
ClusterManager<OffersMarker> saleClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);

gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(rentClusterManager.getMarkerManager()); //<-- THIS DOESN'T WORK
gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(saleClusterManager.getMarkerManager()); //<-- ONLY THIS WORKS
```

My question, how do I attach multiple ClusterManager.getMarkerManager() to infoWindowAdapter setup?

With listeners I used MultiListener but I haven't found a MultiAdapter or anything like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set a single `InfoWindowAdapter` to `GoogleMap` object. In your case it is being overwritten by `saleClusterManager.getMarkerManager()`

But as a workaround you can forward calls to respective cluster managers.

```
gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        View view = rentClusterManager.getMarkerManager().getInfoWindow(marker);
        if( view == null )
            view = saleClusterManager.getMarkerManager().getInfoWindow(marker);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        View view = rentClusterManager.getMarkerManager().getInfoContents(marker);
        if( view == null )
            view = saleClusterManager.getMarkerManager().getInfoContents(marker);
        return view;
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason, view is never null for me, so the same adapter keeps being called...